# How to convert and translate HTML file with KDE Lokalize?

Tags: html, translation

To what format and how can I convert HTML file in order to translate it with Lokalize application?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `xml2po` tool to convert the HTML page to a .po or .pot file in gettext format, which you can then load and translate with Lokalize. Once translated, you can use the same tool to build the translated HTML pages. There are a couṕle of examples of invokation when you call the `xml2po --help` command.

You'll need to [install the gnome-doc-utils package](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-doc-utils) to use the `xml2po` tool

Answer (score 0):

You can use OmegaT for translating those kind of files.
http://www.omegat.org/

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a project in Lokalize and add the HTML file to this project. Lokalize should create a PO file yet it did not work on my computer.

Lokalize uses the poxml package for this task so you can convert your HTML to PO with the [xml2pot/transxx/po2xml](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/xml2pot.1.html) commands.